# How do I mount my OSX partition from Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, mount, mountpoint, hfs+

I'm currently dual booting OSX 10.13.3 and ubuntu 16.04. But today i think i messsed up my kernel cache and i could no longer boot OSX. I need to mount my OSX partition from ubuntu and manually delete the kernel cache. So I installed hfslus and i tried to mount, but it failed.

```
➜ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 238.5 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 6CCD78C4-5E7F-428E-95C6-07B752925E72

Device             Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2   1050624 262000639 260950016 124.4G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p3 262000640 466800639 204800000  97.7G unknown
/dev/nvme0n1p4 466800640 500117503  33316864  15.9G Linux swap
```

My mount attempt

```
 ➜ sudo mount -t hfsplus /dev/nvme0n1p3 /mnt/macdrive
[sudo] password for seun: 
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/nvme0n1p3,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error

   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail or so.
```

I checked syslog and found:

```
➜ dmesg -wH | grep "hfsplus"
[Feb10 11:00] hfsplus: unable to find HFS+ superblock
[Feb10 11:11] hfsplus: unable to find HFS+ superblock
[ +20.703327] hfsplus: unable to find HFS+ superblock
```

Comment: AFAIK 10.13 automatically "upgrades" your partition to the new APFS, which cannot be mounted on Linux.

Comment: What's the output of `sudo blkid /dev/nvme0n1p3`?